# SQL query with poor performances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I inherited from a SQL query that is quite slow to run (2-2mins20 on average) while the amount of data isn't huge.

I'm not yet much comfortable with SQL but I did attempt to use a temporary table variable in order to have a lookup table to find the region associated with each country. It didn't change anything regarding the total cost of the query (which is 4780, found via an EXPLAIN in DataGrid).

I'm unsure of how I could make it faster besides the creation of the right indexes.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Sites.country IN
                ('Australia', 'Hong Kong', 'India', 'Korea, Republic of', 'Malaysia', 'New Zealand', 'Philippines',
                 'Singapore', 'Taiwan', 'Thailand', 'Viet Nam')
               THEN 'APAC'
           WHEN Sites.country IN ('China')
               THEN 'China'
           WHEN Sites.country IN
                ('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland',
                 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lebanon',
                 'Lithuania', 'Netherlands', 'Norway', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Russian Federation',
                 'Saudi Arabia', 'Serbia', 'South Africa', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Turkey', 'Ukraine',
                 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom')
               THEN 'EMEA'
           WHEN Sites.country IN ('Japan')
               THEN 'Japan'
           WHEN Sites.country IN
                ('Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Costa Rica', 'Guatemala', 'Mexico', 'Peru', 'Puerto Rico')
               THEN 'Latin America'
           WHEN Sites.country IN ('Canada', 'United States')
               THEN 'North America'
           ELSE '?'
           END                                                   AS 'Region',
    Sites.country                                                AS 'Country',
    Protocols.number                                             AS 'Protocol #',
    Sites.number                                                 AS 'Site #',
    VisitReports.finalized                                       AS 'Finalized date',
    VisitReports.startDate                                       AS 'Start date',
    VisitReports.endDate                                         AS 'End date',
    VisitReports.visitMode                                       AS 'Mode',
    LEN(REPLACE(VisitReports.remoteVisitDates, ',', '')) / 13    AS '# of remote dates',
    VisitReports.onSiteVisitDates                                AS 'On site dates',
    VisitReports.remoteVisitDates                                AS 'Remote dates',
    VisitReports.visitId                                         AS 'Visit ID',
    CASE
           WHEN R2Answer.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN R2Answer.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
           ELSE '-'
    END                                                          AS 'R2',
    CASE
           WHEN SDR5Answer.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN SDR5Answer.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
           ELSE '-'
    END                                                          AS 'SDR5',
    CASE
           WHEN SDR5_3Answer.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN SDR5_3Answer.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
           ELSE '-'
    END                                                          AS 'SDR5_3',
    CASE
           WHEN SDR6Answer.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN SDR6Answer.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
           ELSE '-'
    END                                                          AS 'SDR6',
    CASE
           WHEN SDR7Answer.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN SDR7Answer.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
           WHEN SDR7Answer.data LIKE '%choice_n_a%' THEN 'N/A'
           ELSE '-'
    END                                                          AS 'SDR7',
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].ActionItems
    WHERE ActionItems.siteId = Sites.id
        AND ActionItems.deletedAt IS NULL
        AND ActionItems.createdAt > VisitReports.startDate
        AND ActionItems.createdAt < VisitReports.finalized)       AS '# created ActionItems',

    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ActionItems.id)
    FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].ActionItemUpdates
        JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].ActionItems
        ON ActionItems.id = ActionItemUpdates.actionItemId
            AND ActionItems.siteId = Sites.id
    WHERE ActionItemUpdates.deletedAt IS NULL
        AND ActionItemUpdates.updateType IS NULL
        AND ActionItemUpdates.createdAt > VisitReports.startDate
        AND ActionItemUpdates.createdAt < VisitReports.finalized) AS '# updated ActionItems',

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].ActionItems
    WHERE ActionItems.siteId = Sites.id
        AND ActionItems.deletedAt IS NULL
        AND ActionItems.closed > VisitReports.startDate
        AND ActionItems.closed < VisitReports.finalized)          AS '# closed ActionItems'

FROM [DB].[SCHEMA].Sites
    JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Protocols on Protocols.id = Sites.protocolId
    JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].VisitReports ON VisitReports.siteId = Sites.id
        AND questionnaireVersion >= 7
        AND visitType = 'ongoing'
        AND finalized IS NOT NULL
        AND VisitReports.endDate > '2022-01-01' AND VisitReports.endDate < '2022-11-11'

    LEFT JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Answers AS R2Answer ON R2Answer.reportId = VisitReports.id
        AND R2Answer.questionId = 'R3'
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Answers AS SDR5Answer
    ON SDR5Answer.reportId = VisitReports.id
        AND SDR5Answer.questionId = 'SDR3'
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Answers AS SDR5_3Answer
    ON SDR5_3Answer.reportId = VisitReports.id
        AND SDR5_3Answer.questionId = 'SDR3.3'
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Answers AS SDR6Answer
    ON SDR6Answer.reportId = VisitReports.id
        AND SDR6Answer.questionId = 'SDR10'
    LEFT JOIN [DB].[SCHEMA].Answers AS SDR7Answer
    ON SDR7Answer.reportId = VisitReports.id
        AND SDR7Answer.questionId = 'SDR4'
ORDER BY [Finalized date]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should look at query's execution plan. It will show you the bottlenecks of your query and then you can add proper indices. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691725/understanding-a-sql-server-execution-plan

Comment: @albina I thought about doing so, but I only have a macbook and I can't install the clients which provide detailed execution plan. Both DataGrip and Azure Data Studio apps on macOS are just providing superficial insights. :(

Comment: Azure Data Studio supports execution plans, @Faringa . It has since version 1.36.

Comment: As a side note, I *really* hope you don't have a database called `SCHEMA` and a *schema* called `DB`; that would be terribly confusing (it is very confusing in your example code).

Comment: Several joins to your table `Answers` probably isn't ideal; some conditional aggregation would likely be better

Comment: @Larnu `SCHEMA` and `DB` are placeholders here, no worries. How conditional aggregation would be used here? I went through some articles, but can't really figure how it really works in my situation.

Comment: I assumed they would be placeholders, but the placeholder "schema" for the database name, and "DB" (which is often an abbreviation for database) for the schema isn't an ideal choice of them

Comment: My bad, I'll edit thank you.

Comment: Your database leaves a something to be desired. There should be a region table, so your query doesn't have to hard code region names. And as to `answers.data`: You are using a relational database system, so why does your answers table have a data colums containing information in substrings? Why is there not a column telling us YES or NO directly? I hope that you have appropriate indexes at least. An index on `answers(reportId)`? An index on `actionitems(siteId)`?

Comment: You are using invalid quotes by the way. If you quote names, the standard SQL quote is double quotes (e.g. `AS "# created ActionItems"`), the SQL Server quotes are brackets: `AS [# created ActionItems]`.

Comment: I agree with you. As mentioned in the original post I inherited from the query right above, but also of the database in the state it is. I will need indeed to change some things around, such as adding a region table etc. It’s just that in the meantime I can only work with how things are in the current state. That’s why I also mostly tried to find ways to improve the performances of this query itself (eg, finding a way to avoid all these JOINs). The next step would be to push for more meaningful changes.

Comment: Adding the DDL, including indexes, for the tables to your question would help us help you. Sample data would also help. The actual execution plan is really what allows you, and us, to focus on the parts of the query that consume the most resources. (If you can't measure it, you can't fix it.) Some things, like pushing all of the `case`/`like` expressions into a _persisted computed column_ might help, but we don't have enough information to go on.

Comment: Please be aware that you can do set showplan_text on even if you are using a client without a nice UI to visualize the showplan for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @conor-cunningham-msft I've been using it, thanks! Do you know if there are any third-party tools to possibly get a view from such plan (from an XML result, for example)?

Comment: @faringa There are first party ways to visualize the queries.  If you use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you can have it visualize the plan for you.  If you enable query store (on by default in 2022 but not in prior versions back to 2016), it has various views enabled in SSMS to show you the plans for queries (and other things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wth `OUTER APPLY` and conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside the aggregation function).

Something like:

```
SELECT
  ...
  s.country                                          AS [Country],
  p.number                                           AS [Protocol #],
  s.number                                           AS [Site #],
  vr.finalized                                       AS [Finalized date],
  vr.startdate                                       AS [Start date],
  vr.enddate                                         AS [End date],
  vr.visitmode                                       AS [Mode],
  LEN(REPLACE(vr.remotevisitdates, ',', '')) / 13    AS [# of remote dates],
  vr.onsitevisitdates                                AS [On site dates],
  vr.remotevisitdates                                AS [Remote dates],
  vr.visitId                                         AS [Visit ID],
  ans.[R3]                                           AS [Answer R3],
  ans.[SDR3]                                         AS [Answer SDR3],
  ...
  act.created                                        AS [# created ActionItems],
  act.updated                                        AS [# updated ActionItems],
  act.closed                                         AS [# closed ActionItems]
FROM sites s
JOIN protocols p ON p.id = s.protocolid
JOIN visitreports vr ON vr.siteid = s.id
                    AND vr.questionnaireversion >= 7
                    AND vr.visittype = 'ongoing'
                    AND vr.finalized IS NOT NULL
                    AND vr.enddate > '2022-01-01'
                    AND vr.enddate < '2022-11-11'
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ai.deletedat IS NULL AND ai.createdat > vr.startdate AND ai.createdat < vr.finalized THEN 1 END) AS created,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ai.deletedat IS NULL AND ai.closed > vr.startdate AND ai.closed < vr.finalized THEN 1 END) AS closed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                    (
                      SELECT NULL
                      FROM actionitemupdates aiu
                      WHERE aiu.actionitemid = ai.id
                        AND aiu.updateType IS NULL
                        AND aiu.createdAt > vr.startDate
                        AND aiu.createdAt < vr.finalized
                    ) THEN 1 END) AS updated
  FROM actionitems ai
  WHERE ai.siteid = s.id
) act
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.questionId = 'R3' THEN
          CASE WHEN a.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
               WHEN a.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
               ELSE '-'
          END
        END) AS [R3],
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.questionId = 'SDR3' THEN
          CASE WHEN a.data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes'
               WHEN a.data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No'
               ELSE '-'
          END
        END) AS [SDR3],
    ...
  FROM answers a
  WHERE a.reportid = vr.id
) ans
ORDER BY [Finalized date];
```

In any way you should have indexes on `answers(reportid)` and on `actionitems(siteid)` to be able to join the answers and action types quickly.

In order to access the YES/NO/- directly, I suggest you add a computed column to your answers table. That will simplyfy above query.

```
ALTER TABLE answers ADD yes_or_no AS (CASE WHEN data LIKE '%choice_yes%' THEN 'Yes' WHEN data LIKE '%choice_no%' THEN 'No' ELSE '-' END) PERSISTED;
```

### UPDATE

Due to two shortcomings in SQL Server, the first `OUTER APPLY` must be split into two steps, otherwise you'll get syntax errors:

```
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    SUM(is_created) AS created,
    SUM(is_closed) AS closed,
    SUM(is_updated) AS updated
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN ai.deletedat IS NULL AND ai.createdat > vr.startdate AND ai.createdat < vr.finalized THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_created,
      CASE WHEN ai.deletedat IS NULL AND ai.closed > vr.startdate AND ai.closed < vr.finalized THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_closed,
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                        FROM actionitemupdates aiu
                        WHERE aiu.actionitemid = ai.id
                          AND aiu.updateType IS NULL
                          AND aiu.createdAt > vr.startDate
                          AND aiu.createdAt < vr.finalized
                      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_updated
    FROM actionitems ai
    WHERE ai.siteid = s.id
  ) precomputed
) act
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I will definitely use indexes (they were not setup originally) and add as well a computed column as you mentioned. I don't have yet 15 pts in reputation, so sadly I can't upvote your answer. I hope someone can upvote you on my behalf.

Comment: I'm not sure I can proceed the way you described, I encountered two errors which originate from the COUNT/MAX within the OUTER APPLYs.

Errors:
```
[S1000][8124] Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.
[S1000][130] Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```
I tried to join visitreports in the OUTER APPLY thinking it was that.

Comment: The suggested computed column (`yes_or_no`) may also be able to accommodate `WHEN data LIKE '%choice_n_a%' THEN 'N/A'`.

Comment: @Faringa: I see. Obviously, SQL Server has some shortcomings when it comes to `OUTER APPLY`. While my query should be syntactically correct, SQL Server complains that it can neither deal with vr columns inside the aggregation function nor with the exists clause. I've updated my answer with an `OUTER APPLY` that circumvents these shortcomings by simply doing the same thing in two steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer and update helped me solve my issue. I learned a lot also along the way, I will now focus on trying to make the db design more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you stated, a `Countries` region lookup table makes the code cleaner. Besides that, I would look for opportunities to reduce data volume from `Answers` and `ActionItemUpdates` if the table size is significant. After that, aggregate `Answers` to `reportId` level; `ActionItems` and `ActionItemUpdates` to `siteId` level. Since `visitType='ongoing'`, it seems that it's 1-to-1 between the two results. The last step is to join them together to get a site-level report.

```sql
with cte_visitReports as (
select id,
       siteId,
       finalized,
       startDate,
       endDate,
       visitMode,
       visitId,
       onSiteVisitDates,
       remoteVisitDates
  from VisitReports
 where endDate > '2022-01-01'
   and endDate < '2022-11-11'
   and questionnaireVersion >= 7
   and visitType = 'ongoing'
   and finalized IS NOT NULL),
cte_answers as (
select a.reportId,
       max(case
              when a.questionId='R3' and a.data like '%choice_yes%' then 'Yes'
              when a.questionId='R3' and a.data like '%choice_no%'  then 'No'
              else '-'
            end) as R2,
       max(case
              when a.questionId='SDR3' and a.data like '%choice_yes%' then 'Yes'
              when a.questionId='SDR3' and a.data like '%choice_no%'  then 'No'
              else '-'
            end) as SDR5,
       max(case
              when a.questionId='SDR3.3' and a.data like '%choice_yes%' then 'Yes'
              when a.questionId='SDR3.3' and a.data like '%choice_no%'  then 'No'
              else '-'
            end) as SDR5_3,
       max(case
              when a.questionId='SDR10' and a.data like '%choice_yes%' then 'Yes'
              when a.questionId='SDR10' and a.data like '%choice_no%'  then 'No'
              else '-'
            end) as SDR6,            
       max(case
              when a.questionId='SDR4' and a.data like '%choice_yes%' then 'Yes'
              when a.questionId='SDR4' and a.data like '%choice_no%'  then 'No'
              when a.questionId='SDR4' and a.data like '%choice_n_a%' then 'N/A'
              else '-'
            end) as SDR7       
  from Answers a
  join cte_visitReports r
    on a.reportId = r.id
 where a.questionId in ('R3','SDR3','SDR3.3','SDR10','SDR4')
    -- additional filters such as createdAt if available to reduce data volume
 group by a.reportId),
cte_action_items as (
select ai.siteId,
       count(distinct case when ai.deletedAt is null and ai.createdAt > r.startDate and ai.createdAt < r.finalized then ai.id end) as created_action_items,
       count(distinct case when ai.deletedAt is null and ai.closed    > r.startDate and ai.closed    < r.finalized then ai.id end) as closed_action_items,
       count(distinct case when iu.deletedAt is null and iu.createdAt > r.startDate and iu.createdAt < r.finalized then ai.id end) as updated_action_items
  from ActionItems ai 
  join cte_visitReports r
    on ai.siteId = r.siteId
  left
  join ActionItemUpdates iu
    on ai.id = iu.actionItemId 
 where 1 = 1
    -- additional filters if possible ro reduce data volume 
 group by ai.siteId)
select coalesce(c.region,'?')                            as 'Region',
       s.country                                         as 'Country',
       p.number                                          as 'Protocol #',
       s.number                                          as 'Site #',
       r.finalized                                       as 'Finalized date',
       r.startDate                                       as 'Start date',
       r.endDate                                         as 'End Date',
       r.visitMode                                       as 'Mode',
       len(replace(r.remoteVisitDates, ',', '')) / 13    as '# of remote dates',
       r.onSiteVisitDates                                as 'On site dates',
       r.remoteVisitDates                                as 'Remote dates',
       r.visitId                                         as 'Visit ID',
       coalesce(a.R2,'-')                                as 'R2',
       coalesce(a.SDR5,'-')                              as 'SDR5',
       coalesce(a.SDR5_3,'-')                            as 'SDR5_3',
       coalesce(a.SDR6,'-')                              as 'SDR6',
       coalesce(a.SDR7,'-')                              as 'SDR7',
       coalesce(ai.created_action_items,0)               as '# created ActionItems',
       coalesce(ai.updated_action_items,0)               as '# updated ActionItems',       
       coalesce(ai.closed_action_items,0)                as '# closed ActionItems'
  from Sites s
  left
  join Countries c
    on s.country = c.country 
  join Protocols p 
    on s.protocolId = p.id 
  join cte_visitReports r
    on s.id = r.siteId
  left
  join cte_answers a
    on r.id = a.reportId
  left
  join cte_action_items ai
    on s.id = ai.siteId
 order by r.finalized;
```

If the report response time is critical, I would try the following approaches:

1. Tune the queries
2. Cache the result (ie. materialized views)
3. Create a datamart for reports and dashboards

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarity of your answer and taking the time to answer! There are a lot of things new to me here and that's great. I will dig more into all of that to fully grasp the changes. I don't have yet 15 pts in reputation, so sadly I can't upvote your answer but I marked it as the answer.

Comment: You must not aggregate ActionItems and ActionItemUpdates to siteId level, because the aggregation is supposed to refer to the selected VisitReports's date ranges. This is the reason I have used `OUTER APPLY` for the aggregation in my answer.